# Why Android Studio shows obsolete HAXM RAM setting dialog during installation

Tags: android, android-studio, haxm

According to the HAXM Installation Instructions:

> RAM setting is obsolete since Intel HAXM 6.2.0

Why Android Studio shows HAXM RAM setting dialog during HAXM installation via SDK Manager?

My environment: Windows 10, Android Studio 2021.2.1, HAXM 7.6.5
Docs: https://github.com/intel/haxm/wiki/Installation-Instructions-on-Windows

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the nature of android studio. If you do not want to set the RAM requirements android studio can live with the recommended requirements. Also android studio is working with different versions of HAXM as per user. The dialog is in place to ensure backwards compatibility.

Comment: IMHO Android Studio does work with the same HAXM installer (placed in 
...\Sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager) and AS
installs exact HAXM version(6.2.0). 
If you run HAXM installer manually, it will not show RAM setting dialogue.

Comment: I meant "AS installs exact HAXM version(7.6.5)"